# Euler equation formula

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, calculus-of-variations

When I am using Euler equation for Fourier transform integrals of type 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x) exp[ikx] $$

I am getting following integrals:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x) cos(kx)$  (for the real part)

and

$i* \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx f(x) sin(kx)$   (for its imaginary part)

I am wondering what is the final integration result though. Is that the sum of both parts or  are they seperate results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration is linear (that is integral of sum is sum of integrals) so yes, final result is sum. I think most od the time it's not convenient to split integrals this way though, because exponents are easier to handle than trig functions.

Comment: Yes, but I am using this method for a computer simulation to compare difference between the analytical method (this one) and the numerical (i.e. Filon's method) for oscilatory functions. I just wanted to know whether I need to sum both of the integrands or not.

Comment: I would also like to know, when the imaginary or real part is being reduced to 0?

Comment: Consider what happens with the integrals if your function is even or odd.